# Why aren't my nodes showing up in the shading tab?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ5ungDgFNc) tutorial to make a donut. However, when I am in the shading tab, nodes are not showing up in the bottom part. I have explored the area, but I can't find the starting nodes[image]

Comment: Do you have the object selected?

Comment: Hmmm. Hard to tell. The box at the top-middle that says "slot" suggests that no material has been assigned to whatever object you have selected.

Comment: Pull from the ball icon that is to the left of "New", existing materials should appear there.

Comment: I know assigned a material, because I can color the object. When I press the ball I can select 'material.003' Even though I selected it, I still cant see anything. Maybe what is needed is a way to send myself to where the nodes are.

Comment: Share your file to take a look

Comment: show the properties panel for the material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose your material, and in the shader workspase go to view-view all
EDIT: For me it was View:Frame All in the bar above the Nodes

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that? Perhaps indicate the menu items used or an image showing the features used

Comment: There is a bar above where the nodes are supposed to show up. In the left part of it, there is a view button. In the drop down that it creates there is a view all button. Hope this helps.